# No validation performed on a Symfony Form if submitted with clearMissing false

Tags: forms, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm building a REST API with Symfony. Let's say I've got the following Doctrine entity:

```
class Car {
    private $model;
    private $make = 'Mercedes';
    /** @Assert\NotBlank() **/
    private $year;
}
```

When I try to create a new `Car` with an HTTP POST request (REST, no browser), if the request doesn't contain any value for the `$make` property, by default the `Form::submit()` method nullifies this field in my entity. As I don't want it to do so, I set its `clearMissing` argument to false. This works fine except now my `@Assert` constraints are not taken into account (as opposed to when `clearmissing` is `true`). For instance the `$year` property doesn't trigger any error if `null`, it looks looks like no validation is performed

So I'd like to know if there is a way to have:

- properties with default values on my entity
- plus no field nullification for missing data
- plus @Asserts constraints respected

#### Note:

I found a two year old [issue on Github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/9998) which describes my problem exactly, but the problem is supposed to be fixed. So it shouldn't be the same as mine...

Answer (score 1):

According to http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html :

1. If you want to use default value, you can use next:

1) for YAML:

```
field:
    options:
        default: "your_value_here"
```

2) for annotations just add to @ORM\Column next:

```
options={default:"you_value_here"}
```

2. to set nullable just add nullable: true option:

1) YAML

```
field:
    nullable: true
```

2) annotations

```
@ORM\Column(...., nullable=true)
```

Comment: This will only affect database level. I'd like my objects to have this default value (without having to repeat the default value in the php property as well, because DRY).

Comment: @marcv have you tried to initialize your object in __construct()?

Comment: Yes, it makes no difference as compared to `private $myProperty =  'value'`. It gets nullified by `submit()` if the `clearMissing` arg is true.

Comment: @marcv I've tested defining of property and it works for me. So, I set `private $myProperty` to `value` in my Entity class and then use `$form->handleRequest();` As result I get predefined value in my form and save it successfully. What are you using for submit ?

Comment: I cannot use handleRequest (AFAIK) because I'm in a REST context. The request doesn't come from a browser. My form's name is not in the request, for example, which is something `handleRequest()` expects. I use `$form->submit($request, true/false)`

Comment: @marcv see also [this](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/585)